# Parsing XML where Parent/Child have same tag

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm working with the popshops api & parsing the XML in beautiful soup.
The data has four levels of categories.
(i.e Furniture is a sub-category of Home & Garden, Baby Nursery Furniture is a sub-category of Furniture)

How can I differentiate the 4 levels of categories when everything has the same tag 'category'.

```
<category id="16000" name="Home & Garden">
 <categories>
  <category id="16669" name="Furniture">
   <categories>
    <category id="17135" name="Baby Nursery Furniture">
     <categories>
      <category id="17146" name="Baby Beddings & Blankets" leaf="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) documentation highlights, you could directly reference their attribute values instead of element or tag name:

```
soup.findAll(id="16000")
```

OR

```
soup.findAll(name="Home & Garden")
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are many ways you can differentiate the same tag using `BeautifulSoup` (I don't know if you have *specific* definition for "differentiate" here). One possible way would be differentiating by the hierarchy/structure. For example, to get only the forth level depth `<category>`s :

```
subSubSubCategory = soup.select("category category category category");
```

Specific for the forth level case, you can also get them by evaluating attribute `leaf="true"` :

```
subSubSubCategory = soup.select("category[leaf='true']");
```

For reference : [BeautifulSoup > CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Side note : you may want to consider using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) directly if all you want to parse is a perfect valid XML.